# Placing m books on n shelves such that there is at least one book on each shelf

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $m \ge n \ge 1$, how many ways are there to place m books on n shelves, such that there is at least one book on each shelf?

Placing the books on the shelves means that:
• we specify for each book the shelf on which this book is placed, and
• we specify for each shelf the order (left most, right most, or between other books) of the books that are
placed on that shelf.

I solve this problem in the following way:

If $m=n$, there are $m!$ or $n!$ ways to do it
Else:

1. Place $n$ books on $n$ shelves: $n!$ ways to do it
2. Call the set of $m-n$ remaining books $T=\{t_1, t_2,..,t_{m-n}\}$
   The procedure for placing books on shelves: choose a shelf, choose a position on the shelf
   We know choosing a shelf then place the book on the far left has $n$ ways
   For book $t_1$, there is a maximum of $1$ additional position (the far right). Thus there is $n+1$ ways to place book $t1$.
   For book $t2$, there is a maximum of $2$ additional positions. Thus there is $n+2$ ways for book $t_2$
   ...
   For book $t_i$, there is a maximum of $i$ additional positions. Thus there is $n+i$ ways for book $t_i$
   In placing $m-n$ books, we have $(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m-n)$ or $(n+1)(n+2)..m$ ways
   In total, we have $n!(n+1)(n+2)...m$ or $m!$ ways

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: "*Given $n\geq m\geq 1$, how many ways are there to place $m$ books on $n$ shelves such that there is at least one book on each shelf*"... So... there are more shelves than books or at least as many shelves as books?  Are you sure you don't mean to have $m\geq n\geq 1$?  If it really were $n\geq m\geq 1$ then the answer is zero for all situations where $n>m$ and $m!$ for all situations where $n=m$

Comment: With the correction $m\geq n\geq 1$, the answer is not $m!$, but is rather $m!\binom{m-1}{n-1}$.  Consider arranging the books in a single row first, then picking $n-1$ different spaces between the books in which you'll place dividers, these dividers representing where one shelf will end and the next shelf begins.

Comment: When a book desires to remain alone on its shelf, it's pure shelfishness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the ordering of the books is important, not merely which shelf they are on, you can simply split any book ordering into shelves by choosing the $n{-}1$ shelf breaks from the $m{-}1$ book gaps. So there are

$$m!\binom{m-1}{n-1} = \frac{m!(m-1)!}{(m-n)!(n-1)!} \text{ options}$$